# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main$1 java?

Tags: java

I have 3 classes in my java program. The main method is in the Main class, but when I compile the classes somehow this  `Main$1` class is created. When I run from eclipse, there is no Exception shown. But when I manually deploy the class as jar files and the program runs just fine, but it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main$1
        at Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't know how to get rid of the Main$1.class. What should I do? The code is pretty big so I am only showing the main class. Here's my code:

```
package calendar;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
        displayCalendar p;
        final Saver save = new Saver();      
        p = new displayCalendar(save);

        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.add(p);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(500,500);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            // Implements all abstract method.

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    save.saveAll();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });        
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: It is an inner anonymous class (eg. a listener, validator, etc)

Comment: Whenever you create an anonymous class it is compiled to the name of the class it was created with a $# on the end. so `Main$1` was the first anonymous class in the Main class.

Comment: You're not bundling your jar correctly, you're leaving out class files generated by the compiler.

Comment: So, what command should I use to compile this type of classes?

Comment: @user139820 the class is automatically compile when you compile `Main.java`. In this case the class is the `WindowAdapter` that you created.

Comment: But why do I get the exception ? It seems the program isn't working correctly too..

Comment: @user139820: Dave Newton already gave you the answer. You have to put *all* class files into the jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main$1 :- An anonymous class.  This inner class gets created due to the following code chunk from your MAIN class But it should not be a problem. you should check your jar file.  JAR file should contain the MAIN$1 class in same folder where MAIN Class exist.

```
 fr.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            // Implements all abstract method.

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    save.saveAll();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });
```