# InternalFrameListener "interrupts" the loading of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener

I have a Jframe that extends ModalJInternalFrame. In the constructor of one class, I'm putting the title and size of the frame:

```
public class ApplicInternalFrame extends ModalJInternalFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ApplicInternalFrame(Component parent) throws CommonException {
    super(parent, "Applic", false, false);
    this.setSize(200, 200);
}
```

In another class I'm creating the GUI in it:

```
public class ApplicabilityChooserPanel extends CdmPanel implements ActionListener, ComponentListener, Runnable {
public ApplicabilityChooserPanel(Component parent, [...]) throws CommonException {
parentFrame = new FrameWrapper(parent);

JInternalFrame test = FrameUtils.getParentInternalFrame(parentFrame.getContentPane());
[...]
buildGUI();

test.addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameAdapter() {
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    });
```

"test" perfectly gets the frame-object, and I can among other see the "Applic" title of the frame through "test". My issue comes on the line with "test.addInternalFrameListener(...)". If I use those last lines of code, Eclipse goes into an "invisible" break point in ClassLoader.class, and the frame does not open at all. 
I need help to get an action to happen when I click the "X" in the window.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I didn't realize that it was created inner clases. Found solution from [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main$1 java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912417/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-main1-java)